# Is Pentax AF360 same as Jessops 360AFD?

Tags: flash, pentax, third-party

I've got a Jessops 360AFD flash and I'm looking for a diffuser for it (the original one is broken). I have been led to believe it is the same as a Pentax AF360.

Is this the case? Or have I had misinformation?

Comment: Are you looking for a push-on diffuser, or to repair the built-in / pull-out wide-angle diffuser panel?

Comment: push on. much easier than trying to repair imo. why? any tips either way?

Comment: A push-on diffuser has a different purpose than a wide-angle panel. If I'm right about which basic model it is, the Sto-Fen OM-MZ3 should fit. This will give more of a bare-bulb effect than the built-in panel.

Comment: I took my camera to an event last week. It was quite a dark room so I took my camera with me, however (as the diffuser is broken) I was getting very harsh light on my subjects (e.g. http://www.flickr.com/photos/tclayson/6417397533/). After researching it would appear that a push on diffuser is what I need to soften the light on the subjects in my photos. I didn't realise the panel was any different. Will the Sto-fen one you suggested do what I need?

Comment: please post that as a new question. :)

Comment: Hmmm.  looks like an interesting little flash.  I am looking to get a couple more strobes (self Christmas present), and these could fit the bill.  I will have to investigate further.  Amazing price for a TTL flash.  Thanks for asking the question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No.** The Jessops 360AFD is almost certainly a relabeled version of the [Tumax DPT386AFZ](http://www.icorpandtumax.com/DPT3Series.htm). This flash is made by Icorp Development Ltd., a Hong Kong company which makes low-cost reverse-engineered dedicated system flashes sold under the Tumax brand and also as what they call ["private label" products](http://www.icorpandtumax.com/company.html).

Other versions of this flash, or other models from Tumax, are sold under brands like Digital Concepts, Vivitar (a brand unrelated to the old-school Vivitar company), Bell and Howell, Bower, and so on. Various versions of this flash often claim slightly different guide numbers, but 36m is on the low side. Presumably a company can order them that way to cut costs — or it's possible that it's just older version than currently offered.

Reviews are mixed; some people are happy with the results for the lower price than the camera-system brands or from bigger third-party flash companies, while others have bad experiences with quality and support. Support is a big deal: in the US, the companies selling these models are basically cheap-chinese-electronics-importers, not camera companies, and customer support is not in their business model. I don't know if that's the case with Jessops. Have you contacted them about the broken diffuser?

Comment: jessops is the biggest camera retailer on the high street in britain. however the flash was pretty cheap (although not cheap enough to replace ). also it is a year or so old now, so i doubt theyd really help out. thanks for the info, i shall do some more digging.

Comment: I think you are right! :) Good detective work there. :) thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Their *guide number* and *zoom range* are the same, but they are certainly not the same model. For example, the Jessops has ability swivel and is available for multiple brands, while Pentax is a dedicated P-TTL capable flash without swivel.

[As reported](http://www.pentaxforums.com/forums/pentax-camera-field-accessories/26507-auto-focus-360-head-demensions-please.html), head size of the Pentax is 2 9/16" wide by 1 5/8" high (65 x 41 mm). Compare that with your Jessops to see if its diffuser might fit.